# Getting 502 Proxy Error while creating file html to pdf in node js

Tags: node.js, apache, proxy, apache2, reverse-proxy

Everything is working on localhost, but I tried to upload code on aws server then I am getting 502 proxy error.

Error is:
**Proxy Error**

**The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.**

**The proxy server could not handle the request**

**Reason: Error reading from remote server**

**Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at servername.com Port 443**

I did some changes according to the server's suggestions like adding keyAlive parameter, setting timeout time and etc but failed to resolve this issue.

```
<virtualhost *:443>
  servername servername.com
  ProxyRequests Off
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
ProxyPreserveHost On
Timeout 28800
ProxyTimeout 300
KeepAlive On
Options FollowSymLinks

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:4000/ retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On nocanon
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:4000/

    <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </proxy>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/servername.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/servername.com/privkey.pem
</virtualhost>
</IfModule>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Any suggestions for this?

Comment: Have you tried a "curl -v http://127.0.0.1:4000/" to make sure it responds alright? Also you can remove <Proxy *> tag entirely. Also Order and Allow directives are deprecated from 2.2, do not use them.